# How to name my packages

Tags: java, design-patterns, model-view-controller, package, naming-conventions

I worked with object oriented programming for a while now and I also used packages a few times.

But I really wonder if there is an easy way to choose the package names? I know the MVC-Pattern, which is fine, but doesn't really apply on all my classes. For example, I have a custom JButton Class, which is a model and a view at the same time... Where should I put such classes?

Are there "golden rules" for package names or are there other patterns? How do you usually name your packages?

Comment: if you have something that is "model and view at the same time" then you do not have anything reassembling mvc there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to follow [this article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html) for general guidelines about packages naming conventions.

In you specific case, if you're using MVC pattern you should organize your classes among the different roles of the pattern. So, for example:

```
com.yourproject.views
com.yourproject.controller
com.yourproject.model
```

**NOTE** If you have a class that is *"model and a view at the same time"*, I suppose you have some design issue. Try to analyze the problem more carefully.

Comment: Well, for my custom JButton Class it's actually correct: I create an entity of my Class "Button" (so it's a model), but I also add it to a JPanel (therefore it's a view too). Or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: @muffin It's difficult for me to say if your design is right or wrong without knowing the whole project. But it's very strange that you have a "mixed-role" entity. So I suppose you don't have a clear vision about the mvc pattern.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it right... I'm using all three MVC-Packages without mixed-role. :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, name your package by classification of your class.
In addition, you can follow the famous open source project, such as apache.